argparse parse arbitary number groups of arguments
I have this snippet for illustrative purpose that doesn't work at all.
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()

parser.add_argument("--action", nargs="+")
parser.add_argument("--number", nargs="+", default=1)
parser.add_argument("--some-parameter-to-action", nargs="+", required=True)

args = parser.parse_args()

I'm trying to parse an arbitrary number of action parameters, each action should have an associated number and some-parameter-to-action, potentially with a default value. Passing another action should create a new one and the following --number and --some-parameter-to-action flags should be associated with the action that preceeded it.
Examples, I want to be able to pass all or a subset of these in a single invocation of the script:
--action say -n 3 --some-parameter-to-action foo
--action bla --some-parameter-to-action no
--action nothing # error

Is something like this possible in python?

argparse provides for custom (argument parsing) actions, which should be flexible enough to do just about anything.  Read the docs.

However, although argparse with custom actions probably can do it, the kind of parameter groups you describe is unconventional, and somewhat at odds with the model that argparse is designed for.  Consider instead a single argparse argument per action, with a value that combines all needed components.  For example, --action say:3:foo --action bla:no.  You may still want a custom argparse action to handle those, but I think you'll find it overall easier to implement.

Why is the third argument 'required'?  And why the 'nargs=+'? Repeat occurences requires action='append'.  The kind of grouping you want is, at best, awkward. Normaly argparse handles each argument independently (and in any order).

Just one '--action' argument with '+' and 'append' should be enough. You'll get a list of lists. After parsing decide for yourself which is the 'name', the 'number', and the 'other' in each sublist.

I agree with the comments. What you have there is complicated and unconventional. Also, the idea of taking the last values as default is a bad idea: it is hard to implement, hard to explain to the end user. Here is my idea of how to implement it, consider the script triplet.py:
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument(
    "-t", "--triplet",
    nargs=3,
    default=[],
    metavar=("ACTION", "NUMBER", "PARAM"),
    action="append",
)
options = parser.parse_args()
print(options)

Some interactions:
$ ./triplet.py -h
usage: triplet.py [-h] [-t ACTION NUMBER PARAM]

options:
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -t ACTION NUMBER PARAM, --triplet ACTION NUMBER PARAM

$ ./triplet.py -t action1 number1 param1
Namespace(triplet=[['action1', 'number1', 'param1']])

$ ./triplet.py -t action1 number1 param1 -t action2 number2 param2
Namespace(triplet=[['action1', 'number1', 'param1'], ['action2', 'number2', 'param2']])

